# Attempt to call a nil value on Lua script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I wanted to create a simple script that keeps klicking the left mouse button via Lua in the logitech gaming software. However, it keeps saying "attemptto call a nil value" on the line "EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents (true)"
Here is my script:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents (true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      repeat
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The message means what it says: `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents` is nil. This means that `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents` hasn't been defined. Perhaps you need to load some library?

Comment: oh well, i dont know about that, I'm new to Lua...

Comment: `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents` exists only in Logitech Gaming Software scripting environment.  The script cannot be run outside of LGS.  Could you provide a screenshot of where you're seeing this error message?

Comment: well, in the scripting editor

Comment: What is the version of the "scripting editor" you're using?

Comment: it's the editor integrated in the Logitech gaming software, i don't know

Comment: @DJNoRealityTXC_TryhardOne - [Might be relevant](https://www.reddit.com/r/LogitechG/comments/7y9ly8/how_to_get_the_enableprimarymousebuttonevents_run/)